# RSSFeed for FBA based site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have FBA sharepoint site. I am trying to use discussion board RSS feed on to Main site home page. When I used RSS Viewer web part. I am getting below error.

```
 RssWebPart: Exception handed to HandleRuntimeException.HandleException 
System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, 
hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 40, position 24.     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)  
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)    
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String[] args)    
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName(Boolean isQName, Int32 startOffset, 
    Int32& colonPos)     
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()     
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()    
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()     
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)    
     at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)     at System.Xml.XmlLoader....
```

What will be the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to link the RSS endpoint in question? My guess is that your RSS's XML has a node with a space as the first character in it's name:

`< item />` instead of `<item />`

Comment: Where can I see this RSS's XML?

Comment: go to the RSS feed such as http://site/listfeed.aspx?List={00000000-000etc} and view source.